# XML conversion Error

Tags: vb.net

I am getting an error when I am converting below string into xml. I am getting special character at RMR tag.

```
<RMR A01="IV" A02="�275929�" A04="4350.00" A05="4350.00" A06="0" /> 
  <REF A01="DS" A03="1754061" /> 
  <DTM A01="003" A02="20151008" A03="0000" />
```

Comment: <RMR A01="IV" A02="�275929�" A04="4350.00" A05="4350.00" A06="0" />
        <REF A01="DS" A03="1754061" />
        <DTM A01="003" A02="20151008" A03="0000" />



At RMR A02 tag I am getting special charecter.

Comment: No use put it in the comments, it belongs in the question.

Comment: In put String
N4*Hyd*TS*9908\ENT*1\RMR*IV* 275929 **4350.00*4350.00*0\REF*DS**1754061\DTM*003*20151008*0000\RMR*IV* 280154 **250.00*250.00*0\REF*DS**1803729\DTM*003*20151103*0000\